# Trying to get an app to work from android 9 to android 11

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have made an app on a galaxy s8 running android 9 as my android 11 device wouldn't work originally. The app scans for advertisement packets and displays the data. It also saves the information to a text file to be graphically represented when exported to excel.

Upon using an APK extractor to move the app across to my android 11 device it crashes upon opening. Here is the code for the App:

```
//Edit to JoelWasserman BLE scanner by Joshua Gascoigne

package com.example.joelwasserman.androidbletutorial;


import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanRecord;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.ParcelUuid;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.renderscript.Sampler;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import static android.R.attr.value;
import static java.lang.String.valueOf;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BluetoothManager btManager;
    BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
    BluetoothLeScanner btScanner;
    Button startScanningButton;
    Button stopScanningButton;
    TextView peripheralTextView;
    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
    private static final int WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CODE=1;
    private static final String FileName = "StoredData.txt";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    int RSSI1;
    int RSSI2;
    int i = 0;
    long CurrentTime1;
    long CurrentTime2;
    StringBuilder X = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder Y = new StringBuilder();
    long startTime;
    long stopTime;



    //File path for data storage
    File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(path +"/My Files/");


    //Initial file creation for 1st broadcaster data
    String fileName1 = "DATASTOREBLE1_" + i + ".txt";
    File file1 = new File(dir, fileName1);
    FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter(file1.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(fw1);

    //Initial file creation for 2nd broadcaster data
    String fileName2 = "DATASTOREBLE2_" + i + ".txt";
    File file2 = new File(dir, fileName2);
    FileWriter fw2 = new FileWriter(file2.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw2 = new BufferedWriter(fw2);



    public MainActivity() throws IOException {
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        peripheralTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PeripheralTextView);
        peripheralTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        startScanningButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartScanButton);
        startScanningButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startScanning();
            }
        });

        stopScanningButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopScanButton);
        stopScanningButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopScanning();
            }
        });
        stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



        btManager = (BluetoothManager)getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        btAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();
        btScanner = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();


        if (btAdapter != null && !btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent,REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

        // Make sure we have access coarse location enabled, if not, prompt the user to enable it
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("This app needs location access");
            builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect peripherals.");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }

    }





        // Device scan callback.
    private ScanCallback leScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {


            // gets data from the BLE scan for broadcasting packets
            ScanRecord Scanned = result.getScanRecord();
            String address = btAdapter.getAddress();
            int Rssi = result.getRssi();

            //Gets advertised packets in a byte array
            byte[] packetData = Scanned.getBytes();
            //gets length of packet data
            int PacketLength = packetData.length;

            StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
            String[] data = new String[PacketLength];
            //conversion to a hex stream from the byte array
            for (byte hex : packetData)
            {
                x.append(String.format("%02X", hex));
            }

            for (int i =0;i<PacketLength;i++)
            {
                data[i] = (String.format("%02X", packetData[i]));
            }

            //generates the current time in milliseconds
            long TimeMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM  HH:mm:ss:SS");
            Date CurrentTime = new Date(TimeMilli);


            //Filters the scan by nameed device, easily changable
            if (new String("SimpleBLEBroadcaster1").equals(result.getDevice().getName()))
            {



                peripheralTextView.append("Device Name: " + result.getDevice().getName() + " Rssi: " + Rssi + " Packet length: " + PacketLength + "\n" +  " Packet Data: " +   "0x" + Arrays.toString(data) + "Scan complete on: " + TimeMilli + "\n"); //Prints data for the first broadcaster
                X =x;
                RSSI1 = Rssi;
                CurrentTime1 = TimeMilli;
                try {
                    bw1.write("Broadcaster1 " + CurrentTime1 + " " + RSSI1 + " " + "\n" );
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,fileName1 + " is saved to\n " + dir, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }


                //filter for second device (required for my Chip design)
            if (new String("SimpleBLEBroadcaster2").equals(result.getDevice().getName()))
            {


                StringBuilder y = new StringBuilder();
                y=x; // Changes the Hex stream detected for the second device to a new variable for storage purposes
                peripheralTextView.append("Device Name: " + result.getDevice().getName() + " Rssi: " + Rssi + " Packet length: " + PacketLength + "\n" +  " Packet Data: " +   "0x" + Arrays.toString(data) + "Scan complete on: " + TimeMilli + "\n");//Prints data for the second broadcaster
                Y=y;
                RSSI2 = Rssi;
                CurrentTime2 = TimeMilli;
                try {
                    bw2.write("Broadcaster2 " + CurrentTime2 + " " + RSSI2 + " " + "\n" );
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,fileName1 + " is saved to\n " + dir, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    };



    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    System.out.println("coarse location permission granted");
                } else {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Functionality limited");
                    builder.setMessage("Since location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover beacons when in the background.");
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        }

                    });
                    builder.show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }


    public void startScanning() {
        i++;
        //re-create file for BLE1
         fileName1 = "DATASTOREBLE1_" + i + ".txt";

         file1 = new File(dir, fileName1);
        try {
            fw1 = new FileWriter(file1.getAbsoluteFile());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bw1 = new BufferedWriter(fw1);
        //re-create file for BLE2
        fileName2 = "DATASTOREBLE2_" + i + ".txt";

        file2 = new File(dir, fileName2);
        try {
            fw2 = new FileWriter(file2.getAbsoluteFile());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bw1 = new BufferedWriter(fw2);
        System.out.println("start scanning");
        peripheralTextView.setText("");
        startScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btScanner.startScan(leScanCallback);
            }
        });

    }

    public void stopScanning() {
        System.out.println("stopping scanning");
        peripheralTextView.append("Stopped Scanning");
        startScanningButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btScanner.stopScan(leScanCallback);
            }
        });
        try {
            bw1.close();
            bw2.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }






}
```

When I remove the code that creates an external storage directory for data storage, the app works on the android 11 device.

How would I change the code for saving data to a text file to work in android 11?

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.joelwasserman.androidbletutorial">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"  android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.joelwasserman.androidbletutorial.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Scan"
        android:id="@+id/StartScanButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/PeripheralTextView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:maxLines="30" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ready to Bluetooth Scan"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Stop Scanning"
        android:id="@+id/StopScanButton"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/StartScanButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/StartScanButton"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You need to update your code support scoped storage to use extremal storage in android 11.

Comment: You can read about the storage changes that came with Android 11 [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) and update accordingly. To be precise, you are using the directories which can no longer be accessed by your app and therefore the problem, had you wrapped your file related code in `try-catch` you would have got an `EACCESS` error stating the same, so that's what your issue is in short

Comment: @gtxextreme Will i need to change my sdk and version of android studio? I currently have API 31 in the "partially installed" status and the build sdk tools 31 installed. I am also using android studio 2.2!

Comment: `When I remove the code that creates an external storage directory for data storage, ` There is no code that tries to do so. You should post code that is problematic. Other code is irrelevant.

Comment: @GAZZA , are you sure it's android studio 2.2 , as this version is at least 3-4 years old. If yes, it's recommended you update as current latest version is 4.3 or 2020.3.1

Comment: @NitishChaudhary Yes it is the example BLE scanner i am using is around 5 years old (also the only one there is) at the start of this project i tried to get it working on a newer version of android studio but had absolutely no luck! the gradle would just never sync. I tried again today and had the same issues